# Removing TabBar Controller when UIBar Button Clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my Application first i have some Login View Controller,after login with button action am moving to Tabbar Controller with Four tabs. my problem is i need to quit that tabbar controller when i click on barbutton and need to come to that loginViewController.please anybody help me in this.actually i have tried some methods but i dint get that. 
Thanks in Advance for Valuable Solution to problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appDelegate place your tabBar and in side loginView ,add this tabBar

```
TUTAppDelegate *appdelegte =(TUTAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[[appdelegte window]addSubview:[[appdelegte motivationalTabBar]view]];
```

On button press remove TabBar

```
TUTAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TUTAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[[appDelegate motivationalTabBar] view]removeFromSuperview]
```

Comment: hai @Rajneesh071.for that code my tabbar controller is removing.but loginview controller is not coming...:(

Comment: hi...are you removing your loginView somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Add your tabBar controller to [appdelegte window] first and then present Login View Controller on it. When user log-ins successfully, dismiss Login View Controller. Again when you click on barbutton to come to that loginViewController , present Login View Controller on tabBar controller. In this case there is no need to add and remove tabBar again and again.

Comment: it is not correct first adding tabbar to window then presenting loginViewcontroller for my context.@Priya. please check question above once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[delegate.window addSubview:delegate.loginViewController.view];
```

i got solution for my problem with this code.
hope this will help for someone.

thanks for all answers.